# Linux kernel compilation locations

Tags: linux, makefile, compilation, kernel, installation

I tried several times to recompile Linux kernel, everything worked fine, but i realized that its taking a lot of space from the hard disk , i would like to know where the newly compiled kernel files located? and is there any temporarily folders that i can clean manually? any files i can safely remove to free up some space ?

I downloaded the kernel source code, copied my kernel Config from /boot/
to the kernel source code
edited it using:

```
make menuconfig
make
make install
```

Comment: `make install` installs all needed files into `/usr/lib/<version>/` directory. After that, you may completely drop **source directory** (where you call `make`) - it is not needed for the working the kernel. However, the source directory and intermediate files created by `make` are useful if you want to recompile the kernel with small changes.

Comment: @Tsyvarev this should be an answer.

Comment: You can do `make clean` to get rid of object files.